# populating a dataframe with value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am looking to make a data frame with two columns. One is a list of numbers, and the other the frequency of occurrence of the first column. So far I have: imported the data, here is an example: should be a 3x6 dataframe.

2 8 13 15 60 67 23

13 25 45 67 68 6

2 8 13 15 61 29
....... so on.
I have separated the columns of this data to its own series.
`firstRowtoSeires = fullNumbersFormated.loc[:,'first']`
from there I get the column but, it's not labeled first. It looks like the 'first' is at the bottom of series. It shows the index and the number corresponding with the index.
example.

0      5

1     18

2     10

3      2

4      4

5     11

6      8

........

Name: first, dtype: int64

But I am looking to add a row that has the frequency of the numbers in a third( or second ) column. And to get the formatting of the column right, so the labels is at the top.
I'v also tried: `countsForFirstRow = firstRowtoSeires.value_counts()`

38    6

45    4

36    4

47    4

34    4

48    4

29    4

33    4

And get this. While this is almost right, I am unable to sort the numbers, it only sorts on the value counts. I feel like I can do everything but what I want with the data. I want to be able to sort the numbers not the value count numbers. And eventually make a 12 column data frame with the **first, second, third, forth, fifth, sixth** set of numbers with the value counts. I have also made my main data a NumPy array but don't know how to sperate the columns to get value counts for that, so I have stuck with pandas, but not afraid to try anything.

first number is the unique number
frequency of number showing in series

```
   8     8

   3     7

  10     7

   2     6

   1     6

  12     6
```

The first column being the index. the second(first) being the unique number in that column. and the third being the frequency that number shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[f'new_{c}'] = df[c].map(df[c].value_counts())
```

Comment: That is so close. Is there a way to combine all the duplicate numbers  or sort by highest frequency . If not this was great and so fast. Thank you so much

Comment: @DavidFlenaugh - Can you add expected ouput from your sample data (3x6 dataframe) in question?

Comment: I am looking to have the output like you have it but, with only unique numbers. For example: the number 5 shows 5 times. I only need it to show up once but indicated that it shows 5 times. That sounds like a mess. let me try again. only unique numbers need to show in the list, but the second column should tell how many times they show. And thank you again.

Comment: @DavidFlenaugh - can you add to question how exactly looks expected output from your data  (3x6 dataframe)? I think data, index and columns. I dont need description, need see how it looks.

Comment: did my last comment show?

Comment: @DavidFlenaugh - in last comment cannot see output DataFrame.

Comment: @DavidFlenaugh - I dont understand 3x6 df -  `2 8 13 15 60 67 23

13 25 45 67 68 6

2 8 13 15 61 29` is input, how is created `first freq

0 8 8

1 3 7

2 10 7

3 2 6

4 1 6

5 12 6` ? It seems data are different.

Comment: The first number is the unique value, the second is the number of time it shows in the data frame. I took out the index. I should have just labeled it.